# android - getMenuInflater cause crash

Tags: android, crash, android-inflate, inflate-exception

I run the following code:

```
   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  
    {
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor shPrefEditor;
public int BlackBackground=0, SleepScreen=1;
static MenuInflater inflater;
public ActionBar ab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    shPrefEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    BlackBackground = mPrefs.getInt("BlackBackground", 0);
    inflater = getMenuInflater();
...
```

The simulator is crash (NullPointerException) on:

```
inflater = getMenuInflater();
```

Anyone know why? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, getMenuInflater() need to move from onCreate to onCreateOptionsMenu().
It seems that there are some devices (Nexus 5 for example) that cause crash if getMenuInflater() is called from onCreate(), and in addition onCreateOptionsMenu() is really the right location.

Comment: I received the same crash and getMenuInflater().inflate() is called in onCreateOptionsMenu(). Any ideas?